# How to join several functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the submit button to be active only if all the fields and filled/selected.

I saw a couple of examples but don’t know how to do it!!

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.envia').prop('disabled',true);
 $('#matricula').on('change', function () 
 {
  $('#envia').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
  
 }).trigger('change');
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.envia').prop('disabled',true);
 $('#peca').on('change', function () 
 {
  $('#envia').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
  
 }).trigger('change');
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.envia').prop('disabled',true);
 $('#quilometros').keyup(function()
 {
  $('#envia').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
 }).trigger('change');
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.envia').prop('disabled',true);
 $('#data').keyup(function()
 {
  $('#envia').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
 }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
<select id="matricula">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Matricula 1</option>
    <option value="2">Matricula 2</option>

</select>
<select id="peca">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Peca 1</option>
    <option value="2">Peca 2</option>

</select>
<input type="text" id="quilometros">
<input type="text" id="data">



<input type="submit" id = "envia" value="ok"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Create a "validition" function that checks the elements to see if the value has changed from the original, and if all elements have changed, enable the button. Then call that function in the event handlers for all the elements etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is you are setting disabled based on individual fields without checking the state of all the others.

you can use one event handler for all but you also need to check all controls each time

```
$(function(){
    // pseudo selector `:input` will match all form controls
    var $inputs = $('#form-id :input').on('change input',validate);

    function validate(){
       var inValid = $inputs.filter(function(){ 
               return !this.value;
           }).length;
        $('#envia').prop('disabled', inValid );
    }
    // also call function on page load
    validate();

});
```

Here I'm using `filter()` to check length of element collection where value is not set

Answer (score 1):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = fun;
            function fun(){
                var matr = $("#matricula").val();
                var peca = $("#peca").val();
                var txt1 = $("#data").val();
                var txt2 = $("#quilometros").val();
                if(matr.length==0 || peca.length==0||txt1.length==0||txt2.length==0)
                    $("#envia").prop("disabled",true);
                else
                     $("#envia").prop("disabled",false);
                    
            }
        </script>
            <form action="#">
            <select id="matricula" onchange="fun()">
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">Matricula 1</option>
                <option value="2">Matricula 2</option>
            </select>
            <select id="peca" onchange="fun()">
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">Peca 1</option>
                <option value="2">Peca 2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="quilometros"   oninput="fun()">
            <input type="text" id="data" oninput="fun()">
            <input type="submit" id = "envia" value="ok">
            </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `onload` instead of document ready? And `oninput` for a button?

Comment: And why replace the proper event handlers, with inline event handlers ?

Comment: @nnnnnn tankyou i fix it.